# Is there any way to decode properly this webpage? I got an error shown on the question

Tags: python, html, decode, encode

Attempted to debug with no success.
Scrape data from website

```
site_url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DUK?p=DUK'
r = urllib.request.urlopen(site_url)
site_content = r.read().decode('utf-8')
```

Saving scraped HTML to .html file (for later processing)

```
with open('saved_page.html', 'w') as f:
    f.write(site_content)
```

Use html.parser to create soup

```
s = BeautifulSoup(site_content, 'html.parser')
```

The outcome of this code is listed below

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-486ff45635ec> in <module>
      3 site_url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DUK?p=DUK'
      4 r = urllib.request.urlopen(site_url)
----> 5 site_content = r.read().decode('utf-8')
      6 
      7 # Saving scraped HTML to .html file (for later processing)

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Please tag the question with the language you are using, and explain the problem in text (Code is important too, but we need some context about the problem)

Comment: Analytical Context. In this case, you will learn the key skill of web scraping – the practice of automatically grabbing information off of online webpages, then parsing and transforming that information into a format amenable to further analysis.

In this case, you will: (1) learn the basics of HTML, which governs almost all static webpages; (2) parse a sample HTML document; (3) extract the necessary info from a single stock's HTML document; (4) scale this process to all symbols; and (5) learn how to scrape the contents of an HTML document from a live webpage in real time.

Comment: Live web scraping of fundamental stock data
IMPORTANT: You must be careful not to become blocked by a website due to excessive scraping. Do not run a loop that continually scrapes a webpage or the webpage will block you from receiving data due to excessive messaging.

Let's explore scraping data from a Yahoo! Finance page. (NOTE: Do NOT run this code block as having everyone do it at once may cause you to get blocked.)

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 can't decode 0x8b as a valid start byte because this makes part from the header  `b'\x1f\x8b\x08`, which points out this is Gzip data. So in order to fetch this HTML page you will have to:

```py
import gzip # to decompress
from io import BytesIO # to do the operations
```

Bringing that up to your code:

```py
import gzip
from io import BytesIO
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site_url='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/DUK?p=DUK'
r = urllib.request.urlopen(site_url)
site_content = r.read() # took off decode('utf-8')

buffer = BytesIO(site_content)
file = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer)
site_content = file.read().decode('utf-8')

s = BeautifulSoup(site_content, 'html.parser')
```

But I highly recommend that you have a look on `requests` library, is not built-in as urllib, but it's much simpler.